# "Ping Connection Pool failed for MySQL. Communications link failure due to underlying exception" Glassfish 4

Tags: java, mysql, database, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I followed this tutorial here:

[Creating and configuring a MySQL DataSource in GlassFish Application Server](http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2008/08/06/creating-and-configuring-a-mysql-datasource-in-glassfish-application-server/)

In step 10, The info I've provided as follow (assuming my database name is **Jsf_demo**):

- DatabaseName: jsf_demo
- Password: thehung1724 (this is my MySQL password)
- URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsf_demo. Where **jsf_demo** is your database name.
- Url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsf_demo. Where **jsf_demo** is your database name.
- ServerName: HUNG-PC (I saw in MySQL)
- User: sa

After that, when I click Ping, i got error:

[image: Error]

**I already copied mysql-connector.jar file to lib folder.**

Hope any suggestion to help me solve this problem.

Comment: try changing serverName to "localhost"

Comment: i did but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your GlassFish, because it's required to get new changes applied.

FYI: here is a [working tutorial](http://docs.jelastic.com/glassfish-connection-pool) regarding GlassFish connection pool, check that.

Edit: I suppose that few properties URL and URl can cause issue you are experiencing.